# Android LiveData Transformation: Changing LiveData object value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I have one LiveData object that holds a list of Users and I am trying to transfer over the data to another LiveData object to be used elsewhere.

I am using MVVM with Room so I get LiveData from the database and on the ViewModel, I am trying to convert the User object in the LiveData to a Person object to show in the UI.

So I have one variable that is `LiveData<List<User>>`

```
class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var age: Integer)
```

and I am trying to convert it to `LiveData<List<Person>>` (as an example)

```
class Person() {

    lateinit var firstName: String

    lateinit var age: Integer
}
```

and the way I am trying to change them is by using LiveData Transformations.map

ViewModel:

```
val list2: LiveData<List<User>> = repo.getAll()
var liveList: LiveData<ArrayList<Person>> = MutableLiveData()
liveList = Transformations.map(list2) { list ->
    val newList: ArrayList<Person> = ArrayList()
    list?.forEach {
        val temp = Person()
        temp.firstName = it.firstName
        temp.age = it.age
        newList.add(temp)
    }
    return@map newList
}
```

but when I run it, it crashes or doesn't update the UI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that it uses `var` in `var liveList: LiveData` instead of using `val`.

You should declare the `liveList` variable like this:

```
val liveList = Transformations.map(list2) { list ->
   ...
}
```

#### Why?

Generally, a `LiveData` variable should always be declared with `val`. The reason is that the purpose of `LiveData` is to allow us to observe the up-to-date value held by the `LiveData`. We do it by code like this:

```
liveList.observe(this) { list ->
    showList(list)
}
```

With this code, we ensure that the updated list is always shown. Whenever the `list` value which is held by `liveList` changes, the UI is updated as a result. But if the `liveList` itself also changes, the code will only observe the first `LiveData` of the `liveList` variable, and the UI will not be updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
val liveList = MutableLiveData(repo.getAll().value.orEmpty().map { user ->
        Person(user.firstName, user.age)
})
```

This would be a more compact way, you could pull out the repo.getAll() call into its own variable if you like